# vue-js-modal - "draggable" issue

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog

I am using [vue-js-modal](https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-modal) to display a draggable and resizable modal but I have an issue with "draggable" property.

The modal is opening and all properties work properly except "draggable"; I can not drag the modal (seems to have no effect).
This is how I set up the modal:

```
  <modal class="vue-js-modal"
      name="modal-name"
      :draggable="true"
      :resizable="true">

    <h1>Modal Title</h1>

  </modal>
```

Can someone help me solving this issue?
Thanks a lot

Comment: The draggable property accepts two data types: String and boolean. You specify it as boolean, could you please try it as String (draggable="true") without colon?

Comment: I tried as String (draggable="true" , without colon) too, but without any result. :(

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what causes the unwanted behaviour at your side. Did you look if there is any error messages interfering with the library or your code? Try from scratch from my code example below
Install the library as: npm install --save vue-js-modal

The following works fine (tested):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="btn btn-primary rounded border" v-html="buttonText" @click="$modal.show('modal-name')"></div>
    <modal class="vue-js-modal"
           name="modal-name"
           :draggable="true"
           :resizable="true">
      <div>
        <h1>Modal Title</h1>
        <p>My happy modal content.</p>
      </div>
    </modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import VModal from 'vue-js-modal'
  export default {
    name: 'Demo',
    components: {
      VModal
    },
    data: function () {
      return {
        buttonText: 'Open modal'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```